# Are [user-research], [usability-study], [testng] and [usability-testing] distinct or should they be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have <del>two three</del> four tags, [user-research](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-research), [usability-study](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability-study),  [usability-testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability-testing) and [testing](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/testing). The tag wiki for testing is `a technique used to evaluate a product by testing it on users` making it clearly about Usability Testing.

All of these fall under User Research. The latter three have been used specifically for usability studies. There definitely needs to be some merges/aliases here.

Which tags are distinct and which should be the master tag(s)? IMO all except User Research need to be combined into a single tag regarding usability studies. I'm less sure whether User Research should be used as a separate but more general tag to include things like Card Sorting that aren't really usability studies. But we definitely don't need all 4 of these, do we?

Answer (score 1):

Testing is (or rather *should* be) separate to usability-testing. The wiki text for it is wrong IMO, but testing itself would encompass more than just usability: It is system testing, user-acceptance testing, unit testing, automated testing... although not all *specifically* associated to UX it is still a recognised term. It is probably being used against the wrong questions here.

My personal opinion is that they are distinct enough terms to warrant separate tags, but we may need to go through and clean up which questions are associated to which tag, and rewrite some of the wiki text.

Comment: IMO just "testing" shouldn't be used for *any* of those questions, it's an ambiguous tag *and* there are better, specific tags. It's not so much a recognized term as an ambiguous, generic term. What would just "testing" be used for? What about usability testing vs studies?

Comment: It's a fair point that testing can also mean other kinds of 'can we break your software' testing (eg load testing, functionality testing).  I guess it depends on a UX board whether when people choose testing they are talking about anything other than usability testing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *usability-study* and *usability-testing* need to be merged. *User research* is a much broader term and can include etnographic studies, observations, interviews, surveys and all manner of research techniques which aren't usability studies. *Testing* is just too generic and these questions should be retagged to something more specific.

Comment: Agreed on all points, but Testing is too widespread to manually retag. Personally I think we should merge into usability-study/usability-testing *without* making them a synonym