# Are questions on testing methodology on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about testing technique (study methods, testing pitfalls, costings and the like) technically on-topic? Testing is obviously a part of UX practice, and it's difficult to imagine where else such questions might go in the SE ecosystem, but they aren't *actually* usability or product experience queries - so do they really belong?

For instance, which of the following five examples would fall within the scope of UX:SE?

1. "How many users should I test with?"
2. "How much should I pay users to test?"
3. "What's the value of exploratory user testing as opposed to task-focused studies?"
4. "Is [Online Testing Service] worth the money?"
5. "How do I spot post-hoc justifications in user tests?"

Answer (score 3):

Usability testing is certainly on topic ([though our tagging is a bit of a mess](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1063/are-user-research-usability-study-testng-and-usability-testing-distinc)).

> User Experience - Stack Exchange is for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers.

If it's a problem one could reasonably encounter as a UXD, HCI researcher (!), IA etc, it's pretty much on topic here. That definitely includes testing. What it excludes implimentation problems like programming/scripting ([try Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)), general workplace issues [try The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) or purely graphic design problems like using Photoshop (try [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)).

Testing is a big part of design, and methodology is a big part of doing testing *right*. If it's important to UX design specifically (or extremely related fields of design), we should (and generally do) cover it. I see testing as something both important and specific to design; unlike coding, which is off topic *because you should ask programmers*, testing is a situation of design where you want to ask *designers and researchers*. Topicality is really as much about *who* you want to ask as it is about *where*.

However with your example questions (granted, they're just examples without clarifying body text) I note some possible problems with constructiveness; particularly #4 is more opiniony and hard to support with facts/practical experience. Say one person had a great experience with Usaura, one person had a terrible one. Both post answers, but do either really help?

As long as these questions are about *solving problems* I don't see a problem with them. I *do* see a problem with "should I use X" or issues comparing *services* rather than *techniques*. But that's not an intrinsic problem with testing questions; we also get "Is X software okay for wireframing" questions which have similar problems.